# Can I use ReactiveSearch components without ElasticSearch?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

Is it possible to use the ReactiveSearch UI components without connecting it to an appbase elasticsearch instance? My site has an existing search API, and I would like to use ReactiveSearch's components with that.

Answer (score 0):

@Avishai It is possible to connect `Reactivesearch` with a different elasticsearch instance. Check this doc here: https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/overview/reactivebase/#connect-to-elasticsearch

Comment: How about connecting the UI components to a non-ElasticSearch data source? For example an existing private REST API.

Comment: Hey this isn't possible as of now. You just want the UI components for your backend to create a search experience ?

Comment: Exactly. I already have a search API in place, but want to use the UI components to build a slick search experience.

Comment: Hey, this isn't possible as of now.